# Eclipse android application dev

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am new to Eclipse, I have recently created an package for illumination bar for xperia devices by using this API

[LINK here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/experimental-apis/illumination-bar-api/)

and when i tried to run it on virtual device i got this error

```
INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
```

any solution for this?

Comment: Post your Logcat stack trace and AndroidManifest.xml here.

Comment: Post your Android Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

try change name package with Caps letters to little letters.

Comment: did not help, still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

As I see the code in the site is malformed due to html tags being displayed in the middle of the code.. So I will try to correct those codes...

1.The item below should be add to the `Uses Permission` section:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.illumination.permission.ILLUMINATION" />
```

(Note that I removed those faulty `<i>` and `<b>` tags that were present in the code. The `<i>` is an HTML tag which is wrong there. **This is why you used to get malformed manifest error.**)

The `<i>` and `<b>` tags are used in `html` to define `Italic` and `Bold` text styles respectively. But they don't have any meaning in the `manifest` file.

2.The code for the intent should be the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_START_LED);
intent.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
intent.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.yourapplication.packagename");
startService(intent);
```

Wrong `<i>` tags again here.

3.The API checking code was right in the website, so I just copy it here:

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_STOP_LED);

     // Evaluate if we have the Illumination Service installed that can receive the intent
     if (null == getPackageManager().resolveService(checkIntent,
             PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER)) {
            //  Not supported
    }
```